# Javascript: Accessing 'action' attribute from Ruby on Rails-generated button

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, forms, button

I have this line of code in my a RoR application view:

```
<%= button_to "Attend Event", attend_event_path(@event), :remote => true, :id => "attend", :class => "tester" %>
```

It generates this code:

```
<form class="button_to" method="post" action="/events/2/attend" data-remote="true">
    <input id="attend" class="tester" type="submit" value="Attend Event" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="1GDsVpuZ4nu3OqSUajEtv2gO4m1QASXcceKlw9FRjbMxKFIIYMr741fSVDA8VeXUAolGyY85d7LpvOjfhs4fVA==" />
</form>
```

Now, one can see that my `id` and `class` got put in the `input` tag; I can't place them in the `form` tag. I need a way to pull out the `/events/2/attend` from the `action` key in the form tag, but I can't add an ID to do so, and document.getElementByClassName isn't working.

Previously, I had a link instead of a button, and `document.getElementById("attend").getAttribute("href");`did the trick, but I'm trying to use a button, not a link.

Could someone suggest to me some Javascript code that would allow me to get the value for the `action` key out (or some ruby code that would allow me to add an ID to the form tag)? I need this value for an Ajax URL.

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Confused by what you're asking. You don't need javascript to get the action. Run rake routes and you can get it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily every form input has a `form` member, pointing to the owner "form", so this simply becomes:

`var formAction = document.getElementById('attend').form.action;`

This has the advantage, that you don't need to care about how your input field is nested, i.e no problem if it is not a direct child of the form.

However, the best way to do it is to add an explicit ID to the form like this:

`form_for @model, html: { id: 'your-form-id' } do |f|`

and access it like `var formAction = document.getElementById('your-form-id').action;`

Comment: Thanks for your response! The first line of code did it for me!

Answer (score 2):

You could traverse to the `parent` from the `child'. If you were not using`jquery`, then the pure`javascript`, you could use either`parentNode`or`parentElement`to get the`parent`.

Try the following:

```
var inputElement = document.getElementById("attend");
var formElement = inputElement. parentElement;
var formAction = formElement.action;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Very useful to know how to traverse elements in this manner.